# How do you add a certificate authority (CA) to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

My work has decided to issue their own [certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) to handle different aspects of our work securely without paying for certificates.

- Cryptographically sign emails
- Encrypt email contents
- Make access to things like the company [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) client-certificate based.
- Revoke the keys of former employees automatically

They sent me a `.pem` file, and I'm not sure how to add it to my Ubuntu install. The instructions sent were: *"Double-clicking on it on a Mac should install it."*

How do I proceed? Do I need to do something with [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) to create a `.key`, `.csr`, or `.crt` file?

Comment: the comment "The instructions sent were: \"Double-clicking on it on a Mac should install it.\"" made my day

Comment: @mzoll and the way of escaping those quotes

Comment: @HosseyNJF, he's quoting them for us, to make sure we parse them correctly when we read them. Ultimate accuracy. Obviously a hard core old school hacker.

Comment: @mzoll, I particularly liked the "should". They hadn't even tried it once. That's some serious IT "support".

Answer (score 388):

## Installing a CA

Copy your certificate in PEM format (the format that has `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` in it) into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and name it with a `.crt` file extension.

Then run `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

*Caveats:* This installation only affects products that use this certificate store. Some products may use other certificate stores; if you use those products, you'll need to add this CA certificate to those other certificate stores, too. ([Firefox Instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/firefox-adding-trusted-ca/), [Chrome Instructions](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-do-I-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome-), [Java Instructions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/java-add-certificate-ca-store/))

## Testing The CA

You can verify if this worked by looking for the certificate that you just added in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (which is just a long list of all of your trusted CA's concatenated together).

You can also use OpenSSL's s_client by trying to connect to a server that you know is using a certificate signed by the CA that you just installed.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect foo.whatever.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, ST = Virginia, O = "Whatever, Inc.", CN = whatever.com, emailAddress = admin@whatever.com
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Virginia, L = Arlington, O = "Whatever, Inc.", CN = foo.whatever.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Virginia/L=Arlington/O=Whatever, Inc./CN=foo.whatever.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Virginia/O=Whatever, Inc./CN=whatever.com/emailAddress=admin@whatever.com

... snip lots of output ...

    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1392837700
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

The first thing to look for is the certificate chain near the top of the output. This should show the CA as the issuer (next to `i:`). This tells you that the server is presenting a certificate signed by the CA you're installing.

Second, look for the `verify return code` at the end to be set to `0 (ok)`.

Comment: this one actually works

Comment: Thanks for noting that firefox / chrome do not use the default cert store.

Comment: Note that update-ca-certificates can be very finicky (probably by design). mycert.pem.crt did NOT work, but mycert.crt did. I also think that it needs to be /usr/local/share/ca-certificates, not /usr/share/ca-certificates (despite what comments said in the /etc/ca-certificates.conf).

Comment: Thanks for the `crt` extension comment, that was the secret to getting this work for me, I was given a cert with a `cert` extension and was confused as to why nothing was working.

Comment: One caveat: `s_client` doesn't send SNI by default and the server may need SNI especially if it supports virtual hosts/sites with different certs; for this case add `-servername foo.whatever.com`. Or if it's a *web* server use (modern versions of) `curl` or `wget` which do SNI automatically.

Comment: It is actually good to complement with @missmah's answer: After copying the certificates into /usr/share/ca-certificates you can execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` so you don't need to manually add the certificate lines in /etc/ca-certificates.conf and don't need to execute update-ca-certificates, since dpkg already does these 2 steps.

Comment: This worked to get the certs in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` but `apt` is still failing on everything saying "Data from such a repository can't be authenticated"  Is this a different problem?

Comment: @endolith Probably a different problem. `apt` often uses HTTP links (not HTTPS) so that certificate authorities are usually not involved. Instead, `apt` uses GPG keys to authenticate downloaded files. You should try searching for Q&A related to `apt` keys, `sources.list`, etc. or ask a new a question.

Comment: @mehaase Ok thanks, it's a corporate firewall issue, I thought it was just SSL interception like everything else

Comment: IT at work had set them selves up as CA, and their automatic rollout had installed the certificat in IE and chrome. But Firefox, virtual machines and everything else didn't know about the certificate. This answer was very helpful in determining and fixing the issue. Thanks a bunch

Comment: The fact that the certificate should be in PEM format but named .crt was the thing that helped me, thanks for the detailed answer, I was able to convert to PEM and finally get it working.

Comment: this really helpfull for me. i already spend 2 days for this missconfigure. thanks mate

Comment: I'm still getting "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate" when running 'openssl s_client -connect company.server:443' - Running my curl commands with -k is starting to look like the only intelligible approach to certificate handling...

Comment: I had to add --fresh to get it to work. e.g. `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh`

Answer (score 93):

[man update-ca-certificates](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html):

```
update-ca-certificates  is a program that updates the directory /etc/ssl/certs to hold SSL
certificates  and  generates  ca-certificates.crt,  a  concatenated  single-file  list  of
certificates.

It  reads  the  file  /etc/ca-certificates.conf.  Each  line  gives  a  pathname  of  a CA
certificate under /usr/share/ca-certificates that should be  trusted.   Lines  that  begin
with  "#"  are  comment lines and thus ignored.  Lines that begin with "!" are deselected,
causing the deactivation of the CA certificate in question. Certificates must have a  .crt
extension in order to be included by update-ca-certificates.

Furthermore  all  certificates  with  a  .crt  extension  found below /usr/local/share/ca-
certificates are also included as implicitly trusted.
```

From the above, I would infer that the preferred way to get local certificate files into the trusted store is to put them into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, and then run `update-ca-certificates`. You do not need to touch `/etc/ssl/certs` directly.

Comment: Naming the certificates with .crt extensions seemed to be required as well.

Comment: Thanks for the note @phyzome -- would not have been able to add my cert otherwise.

Comment: I had to add `--fresh` to get it to work. e.g. `update-ca-certificates --fresh`

Comment: `--fresh` was not needed for me. Just copy into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` with a `.crt` extension and then run `update-ca-certificates`. I had 2 certificates in my PEM file so I had to split it into 2 separate ones.

Answer (score 24):

The other answers regarding `update-ca-certificates` are correct for applications that read from the system certificate store.  For Chrome and Firefox, and probably some others, the certificate must be put in the nssdb, the backend for the Mozilla NSS library.

From
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement:

> For example, to trust a root CA certificate for issuing SSL server certificates, use
>
> certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n <certificate nickname> -i <certificate filename>

Where `<certificate nickname>` is arbitrary, and `<certificate filename>` is your .pem or .crt file.

Other helpful references:

- General description: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Security_Services
- `certutil` man page, describing the parameters used above: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS_reference/NSS_tools_:_certutil

Comment: thanks. It works on Ubuntu 16.04 for Chrome 53.0.2785.143, but Firefox 49 seems to have separate store db and must be added from about:preferences#advanced [View Certiticates] -> [Authorities] -> [Import]

More about firefox cert store. http://askubuntu.com/a/248326/535154

Comment: By the way, if you want to install cert *before* first run of Chrome (i.e. while .pki/ dir is still missing), you must first create the nssdb: `mkdir -p $HOME/.pki/nssdb && chmod -R 0700 $HOME/.pki && certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -N --empty-password`

Comment: There is a way to get Chrome and Firefox to read from the system certificate store. See my answer: https://superuser.com/a/1312419/506107

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. Can now use Slack and Teams Preview behind Corporate SSL Decrypt flawlessly.

Comment: ... Exported ASCII chain, added to the general store, added to the mozilla db... DONE! Chrome instantly stopped nagging me about it. Firefox still says unknown issuer... fantastic

Comment: Firefox allows you to configure security modules... it does not use the same one chrome uses by default... you can add it by loading `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so` to the list of security modules under firefox Certificate settings. Super easy once you know.

Comment: For Firefox to use the sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb NSS store one has to run it with the environment variable NSS_DEFAULT_DB_TYPE=sql. Otherwise Firefox takes the current Firefox profile folder as store. See https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB_Howto

Answer (score 19):

I had same issue, and I had to copy the `.pem` file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, renaming it as `.crt`. The `.cer` file can easily be converted to `.pem`, with openssl, for example, if you don't have the `.pem`.

After copying the file you must execute `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Comment: `openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

Answer (score 15):

For newer builds based on Debian, you may need to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

*NOTE: sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates calls update-ca-certificates internally*

You'll of course still need to copy the certificate (.crt file) to /usr/share/ca-certificates before you do any of this :)

Comment: Thanks so much. after hours of trying to fix it, this only worked for me

Comment: Warning: from what I understand this isn't about newer system, but is about using /usr/share/.. (selectable which are trusted) instead of /usr/local/share/... (all are always trusted) - haven't tested it but that's what I understand based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690833/how-to-run-dpkg-reconfigure-ca-certificates-noninteractively and this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/oala/1.3.5?topic=SSPFMY_1.3.5/com.ibm.scala.doc/config/iwa_cnf_lgst_sys_ca_t.html and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150090/usr-share-vs-usr-local-share-where-to-install-ca-certs/1397209#1397209

Answer (score 11):

Building on dwmw2's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1155710/506107), you can actually tell applications that use NSS for its certificate management to use the system trust store.

`libnss3` by default ships with a read-only set of root CA certificates (`libnssckbi.so`), so most of the time you need to manually add them yourself to the local user trust store located in `$HOME/.pki/nssdb`. `p11-kit` offers a drop-in replacement for `libnssckbi.so` that acts as an adapter to the system-wide root certificates installed in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

**Edit:**

There seem to be more versions of `libnssckbi.so` out there than just in `libnss3`. The following is a script to find them all, back them up, and replace them with links to `p11-kit`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y p11-kit libnss3
find / -type f -name "libnssckbi.so" 2>/dev/null | while read line; do
    sudo mv $line ${line}.bak
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so $line
done
```

**Original instructions:**

To do this, install `p11-kit` and `libnss3` (if they are not already instealled):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y p11-kit libnss3
```

Then backup the existing `libnssckbi.so` provided by `libnss3`:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so.bak
```

Finally, create the symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so
```

To confirm that it worked, you can run `ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so` and it should show the link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Apr  9 20:28 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
```

Now, if you add a certificate to the CA store using `update-ca-certificates`, those certificates will now be available to applications using NSS (`libnss3`) such as Chrome.

Comment: I've been fighting Ubuntu 18.04 to try and get this to work for the past 3 days and it won't work for whatever reason. I link the p11-kit-trust.so to the libnssckbi.so but when I do that there are _no_ certificates at all any longer. Any website I go to thats https enabled (which is basically all of them) prompt that there is a security issue. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: This is brilliant and worked a charm for Firefox anyhow. The script suggested is dangerous mind you. I'd suggest trying the find alone first on your system to see what it finds. I have a huge systems and it turns up stuff in timeshift backups for exmple and I also have a few sshfs mounts at any one time depending on what I'm working on and it trundles off onto those as well. I'd use `locate` in any case to find them and patch them one by one or write a script that loops through specified files only.

Comment: @KevinVasko I'm on 20.04 and no trouble. Only tried Firefox but it worked fine. I take notes when I do things like this and keep them, and noted for myself, that these are .so files, so binary object files, and to be sure Firefox is using the new on you have to shut down Firefox and restarted it. But you are alas, not very clear what you mean by  "there are no certificates at all" - in what context? In `/etc/ssl/certs`?

Comment: wow, I tried so many (obvious) things, this is the only thing that worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As noted, various applications using NSS have their own certificate store. As things stand on Ubuntu, you have to manually use `certutil` to add your CAs for each application, for each user.

In other distributions like Fedora, this kind of thing Just Works™ and you should file a bug against any applications which doesn't automatically trust the CAs you install with `update-ca-trust`.

You can fix this in Ubuntu too by installing the `p11-kit-modules` package and then replacing the NSS *built-in trust roots* module with `p11-kit-trust.so`, by making a symbolic link for example from `/usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so`

Then you *will* get the system's configured trust roots, not some hard-coded ones. Note that Ubuntu ships multiple *different* copies of that libnssckbi.so library with the hard-coded trust roots, and you have to replace all of them!

cf. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss/+bug/1647285

Comment: When I did `sudo find / -type f -name "libnssckbi.so"`, It found `libnssckbi.so` in three places: `/usr/lib/thunderbird/`, `/usr/lib/firefox/`, and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/`. So you are saying that I should link the `libnssckbi.so` in all three of those folders to `p11-kit-trust.so`?

Comment: Okay, just confirmed that linking `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libnssckbi.so` -> `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so` worked like a CHARM. I was able to add a certificate into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, run `sudo update-ca-certificates`, and PRESTO, Chrome started to accept the self-signed certificates.

Comment: @dwmw2 I've been fighting Ubuntu 18.04 to try and get this to work for the past 3 days and it won't work for whatever reason. I link the p11-kit-trust.so to the libnssckbi.so but when I do that there are no certificates at all any longer. Any website I go to thats https enabled (which is basically all of them) prompt that there is a security issue. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Seriously stupid answer to add here, but I had spent 2 hours going back and forth with certutils in Linux. I was sure everything was correct:

```
hutber@hutber-mint /var/www/asos-mvt-framework $ certutil -L -d sql:${HOME}/.pki/nssdb

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

anyproxy                                                     CT,, 
rootCA                                                       CT,, 
myasos                                                       CT,,
```

But still, in Chrome nothing was working. I tried everything. In the end, restarting Chrome was the key to my success after following [Steven Monday](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu#437377)'s advice.