# General getting started with untrusted https

Tags: linux, networking, https, openwrt, ipython

I have about 9 year's experience creating/maintaining minimally secured personal or departmental web sites with Linux and Apache httpd.

Recently I've deployed a couple of web apps that require a https connection.  I usually get an "untrusted connection" warning from my web browser.  Two examples are public access to an OpenWrt uhttpd LuCi page over port 443, and public access to a Beaker Notebook (http://beakernotebook.com/faq), running on Ubuntu 14.04.  I think the embedded webserver is nginx.

Are there general tutorials on this subject that I should be reading (as opposed to asking for "help with untrusted LuCi connection" and "help with untrusted Beaker connection?")

I know almost nothing about certificates.

[image]

Comment: Its not clear what your question is.  I presume if you are connecting to a LuCi page, you trust the site, which means you trust any certificate that might be used.  So just add the certificate to the certificate store and indicate you trust the certificate.

Comment: Within my LAN , I connect to LuCi and Beaker without https.  It not a matter of whether I trust the sites, its a matter of the warning from web browsers and the steps required to convince the browser to open the page.  I'd like to share the Beaker site with some colleagues who will not be comfortable with the  browser warning.  If there are any certificates in place, I didn't install them.  That's probably what I don't understand yet.

Comment: Right.  So add the certificates to the certificate store, then those secure connections, will be trusted.  How you do that is platform dependent.

Comment: @Ramhound : thanks.  Beaker is running on Ubuntu 14.04.  Can you suggest any learning materials for this?

Comment: You don't know how to add a certificate to the certificate in Ubuntu?  Go look it up.  If you are using Firefox, it has its own certificate store, so add it to Firefox use the proper  procedure.  Chrome uses the OS's certificate store.

Comment: @Ramhound is this the kind of thing you're talking about?  https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

Comment: Sure;  [http://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268637/how-can-i-add-an-ssl-client-certificate-key-globally-in-ubuntu)