# OpenSSL with added CA certificate on CentOS

Tags: centos, ssl, certificate, openssl

So the problem is: I'm trying to add CA certificate on CentOS (on server) and check the working of SSL of one of my clients domain.

The same thing works perfectly on Ubuntu:

[How do you add a certificate authority (CA) to Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu)

But on CentoOS we adding certificcate in a different way. So I've add certificate with putting it in: `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` run `update-ca-trust extract` which put it in to the bundle file - so is ok - but when i try to run: `openssl s_client -connect my-domain:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs` I get:

```
(...)
Verify return code: 21
```

So I try to find the solution and I placed it in the `/et/pki/tls/certs` as a `.pem` file add I run `c_rehash`. Now I point `-CApath /et/pki/tls/certs` and I'm getting:

```
(...)
Start Time: 1464599333
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)
```

Can anybody helps with this?