# Why Opera browser gets NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID error for a website with self-signed certificate and does not allow to get in?

Tags: security, certificate, opera

Test link: https://self-signed.badssl.com/

So, it says:

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
> information  from self-signed.badssl.com (for example, passwords,
> messages, or credit cards).
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID
>
> self-signed.badssl.com normally uses encryption to protect your
> information. When Opera tried to connect to self-signed.badssl.com
> this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials.
> This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be
> self-signed.badssl.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the
> connection. Your information is still secure because Opera stopped the
> connection before any data was exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit self-signed.badssl.com right now because the website
> sent scrambled credentials that Opera cannot process. Network errors
> and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work
> later.

- Opera version: Version:92.0.4561.61 (arm64) (the latest)
- OS: MacOS

**Chrome**, for instance, works fine, it gets NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error and allows to get in.

So, both browsers block websites with invalid certificate. But **Chrome** allows to proceed to website but **Opera** does not.

Question: how to make **Opera** work in the same way?

This setting [opera://flags/?search=cert#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure](https://opera://flags/?search=cert#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure) did not help.

By the way, **Safari** (MacOS) blocks it as well.
[image]

Comment: Opera is based on Chromium, so if Chrome, Edge, and Chrome all of the problems, then the problem is with the certificate. You don't mention what version of Opera. Care to provide a little bit more information? [Chromium](https://superuser.com/questions/1495449/how-to-remove-your-connection-is-not-private-in-google-chrome-in-my-developmen/1532843#1532843) make sure the self-signed certificate is imported as a Root CA.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sure, it's the latest one (added), just didn't mention this as everything is updated, pardon.

Comment: @Ramhound, the certificate import is a long way but probably could be an option. The question is how to make Opera work in the same manner like Chrome does?

Comment: Just downloaded certificate and added it into system certificates list and Opera stopped blocking me. Yes, this is a workaround. And still long way.

Comment: It's not a workaround.  It's the standard operating procedure if you want to use, a self-signed certificate, that's been the reality for several years now. As I suggested, Opera, based on Chromium, will follow whatever Chromium does (with a small time lapse)

Comment: Got it. So, Chrome and Opera based on Chromium why they have different behavior =)