# Certificate authority (CA) in Ubuntu 21.10 is installed but it does not work

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I've installed [certificates](https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) before within Windows and Ubuntu [server] and it works normally, but today I tried to install certificates on Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 over RDP + AD user, and it does not work as expected:

- I installed the CA certificates via:

  ```
  sudo mv euro-ca.crt euro-sub-ca.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/
  sudo update-ca-certificates
  ```
- I checked the certificate and it gives me this output, but it does not work in Chrome/Firefox; I cleared cache, cookies, rebooted Ubuntu, and logged in as another user [local admin]:

  ```
  openssl s_client -connect firewall.euro.adroot:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs

    CONNECTED(00000003)
    depth=2 CN = euro-ca, C = FR, ST = *************  verify return:1
    depth=1 CN = euro-sub-ca, C = FR, *************  verify return:1
    depth=0 CN = firewall.euro.adroot, *************  verify return:1
    ---

    ---
    Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
    SSL-Session:
        Protocol  : TLSv1.3
        Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        Session-ID: ******************************
        Session-ID-ctx: 
        Resumption PSK: *************************************
        PSK identity: None
        PSK identity hint: None
        SRP username: None
        TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 600 (seconds)
        TLS session ticket:
        0000 - 63 af b7 *************************23 **   c.. ..I*****..#.
        0010 - 37 cf ***********************8 42 4f **   7..#*******..BO.

        Start Time: 1640439082
        Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
        Verify return code: 0 (ok)
        Extended master secret: no
        Max Early Data: 0
  ```

  [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have their own CA stores on Linux systems. You need to import the CA in each of these browsers.

Comment: I tried same config in centos and it works without importing certificates into browser root certificates. Maybe it is an issue with ubuntu?

Comment: Is the euro-sub-ca being delivered by the server?  If not, then you'll need to install/trust it, as well.

Comment: Yes, and I installed both euro-ca && euro-sub-ca. As I said I made the same configuration in centos and it works but not in ubuntu